# Game over screen monogame

Tags: c#, visual-studio, screen, monogame

I am making a game using the Monogame engine and I just need help on one part of my code. Now, every time the character dies in the game, the code just ends. this is because of these lines of code.

```
else
{
    System.Environment.Exit(0);
}     
if(y <  0)
{
    System.Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Now I want the game to have a 'game over' screen every time a user collides with one of the obstacles and this screen will allow you to go to the menu and allow users to play again. the classes I have at the minute is the game1.cs class, the character class and the obstacle class. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: As written, this question is too broad to be adequately answered on SO. What I can say, though, is that you should do some research on how to implement a [state machine](https://www.google.com/search?q=game+design+state+machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to keep track of the game state.  As an example -- you might only have two states "Playing" and "GameOver".  Instead of exiting in your code snippets, set the game state from "Playing" to "GameOver".

Now in the Update call -- you'll want to check for user input during GameOver and allow them to exit the game completely or start a new game.

In the Draw call -- you'll want to check the game state to decide what to render to the screen.